# How do I stream a SoundCloud users tracks?

Tags: java, android, soundcloud

This is the very first app that I am building, so I am not very knowledgeable. I have followed to tutorial here http://www.sitepoint.com/develop-music-streaming-android-app/ and created a very simple music streaming app. However, it only streams whatever random songs that come from I am not really sure where. I have researched and found that the endpoint should be /users/{userid}/tracks. But I guess I am not completely sure how to implement this. I adjusted the URL from the base endpoint to many combinations of the the (https://api.soundcloud.com/users/{userid}/tracks) I can think of or see. Am I changing the wrong thing? Do I need to change more the just the stored URL?

Extra information - Using android studio
                  - can't post api reference link because of low reputation but its not hard to find

Answer (score 0):

The api endpoint you have is correct, but you need to pass your clientId on every request.  Sign up for SC developers [here](http://soundcloud.com/you/apps).  If you clientID is `9038420384208424` your api call request should look like this:

`api.soundcloud.com/users/duvetcover/tracks/?client_id=9038420384208424&limit=200&linked_partitioning=1`

The `&limit=200` and `&linked_partitioning=1` are optional parameters.  The `limit` parameter will specify how many entries to show.  The maximum is 200.  `linked_partitioning=1` allows for pagination.  It gives a `next_href` key at the end of the request so you can access the next page of followers, favorites, tracks or whatever you are querying.